# Prevent concurrent execution of related tasks in a thread pool or executor service

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have a queue of Runnables to execute that I would like to process using a thread pool. However, some of the tasks in the queue are related to each other (could be implemented by a common hashcode() on the Runnable) and must not be processed concurrently, so, when taking a task off the queue, I would like to check that no currently executing task is related, and if it is, hold back the new task until the related one has completed, but allow other, unrelated tasks to continue (maintaining high throughput is important)

I could do this by a customised ThreadPoolExecutorService and BlockingQueue that tracks the hashcodes of tasks in progress but this is somewhat complex and unwieldy.

is anyone aware of an elegant solution to the problem?

Comment: how are they related to each other? if they have an object in common maybe you can define it as synchronized, to make sure not to access it until the previous thread has finished working with it.

Comment: Why not just customize it to run `List`s of tasks, if there's only one task in the list it will be executed according to your process, and when there is more than one the tasks are queued as to not run concurrently.

Comment: I would require a sort-order on the queue and make the sort order take into account dependencies.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to add items to the queue when they are not cleared to run? My approach would be to have some kind of resource lock on the items and only put them into the queue if they are not locked.

Comment: You could also consider some variant on the [Striped Executor](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue206.html) described by [Dr. Heinz M. Kabutz](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/).

Comment: Tasks are being added all the time,so a new task may be placed on the queue while a related task is executing. Use of synchronized, or not placing an item on the queue will block the threads that are placing items on the queue, which is not acceptable. I'll look at striped executor. Thanks